# Symfony's Command : No default connection

Tags: php, symfony, orm, command

In my Symfony2 project, I need to do some work in database with a Command.
When I launch it, I have this error :

```
[Exception]
There is no default connection
```

I don't understand why ?

My code :

```
1. $this->output = $output;
2. $this->writeln( 'ImportBase' );
3. $importBase = Model\ImportBase::builder()
        ->whereEgal('termine', 0)
        ->limit(1)
        ->getObject();
```

For information, there is just one connection in my project.
Also, I do not use Doctrine but ORM (I guess ? This is not my project)

Do you have any idea ? I can't find anything...

EDIT :

config.yml :

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection:   default
        connections:
            default:
                driver:   "%database_driver%"
                host:     "%database_host%"
                port:     "%database_port%"
                dbname:   "%database_name%"
                user:     "%database_user%"
                password: "%database_password%"
                charset:  UTF8


    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        auto_mapping: true
```

Parameters.yml

```
parameters:
    database_driver: pdo_mysql
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_port: null
    database_name: [...]
    database_user: [...]
    database_password: [...]
```

Model :

```
<?php

    namespace xxx\xxxhBundle\Model;

    use xxx\ORM\Model;

    class ImportBase extends Model
    {
        protected static $table_name = 'import_base';
        protected static $primary_key = 'import_base_id';
    }
```

Builder in Model file

```
    /**
     * Get command builder for the class
     *
     * @return DbCommandBuilder builder
     */
    public static function builder() {

    if( static::$table_name == null )
        throw new \Exception('Canot get builder, table_name is not set');

        $builder = static::dbConnection()->builder( static::tableName(), static::$builder_class );

        $builder->setFetchClassName( get_called_class() );

        return $builder;
    }
```

Comment: Show your db configuration, please (as I understand it is propel orm os smth like it)

Comment: And could you provide code of Model\ImportBase class (or at least builder() method) - I think this error's going from somewhere there.

Comment: Message edited. The Model is very short, but it works  !

Answer (score 0):

That seems a little strange... I don't notice anything wrong based on the configuration you've supplied.

However, since you appear to only have one `dbal` connection, you could simply use the "terser" configuration:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   "%database_driver%"
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%               
        charset:  UTF8
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        auto_mapping: true
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: At first it was like you wrote. I changed because of the error, without success... But thanks.